# How does a $y(t)=$plot of this exponential function looks like?

Tags: complex-numbers

I've tried to plot the y(t) function, but there are complex numbers and I don't know how to plot it. I've been looking for hyperbolic functions transformation, but I didn't figured how to do this. My question is how to transform this in hyperbolic functions and plot it in the y vs t axes.

y(t)=(0.62*exp(-0.564*t)+1)*((-1.62+0.0749*i)/(exp((0.0510+0.24*i)*t))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the complex exponential:  $\exp((0.510+0.24i)t)=\exp(0.510t)\exp(0.24it)=\exp(0.510t)(\cos(0.24t)+i\sin(0.24t))$.  Then if you multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos(0.24t)-i\sin(0.24t)$ the denominator becomes real.  You can then calculate the real and imaginary parts in a spreadsheet over whatever range you want and graph them.

Answer (score 1):

Explore it with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%280.62%2aexp%28-0.564%2at%29%2b1%29%2a%28%28-1.62%2b0.0749%2ai%29/%28exp%28%280.0510%2b0.24%2ai%29%2at%29%29)

Comment: Ok thanks, but how would i do to plot in a wider range  such as 0 to 50 in the time  and 0 to 100 in the y ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be what you might be looking for. But the results does not render anything knowledgeable when y -> {0,100}, but here is the plot anyways.

- [Plot of y(t)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%280.62%20Exp%5B-0.564%20t%5D%2b1%29%2a%28%28-1.62%2b0.0749%2ai%29/%28Exp%5B%280.0510%2b0.24%2ai%29%2at%5D%29%29,%20%7By,0,100%7D,%20%7Bt,0,50%7D%5D)

Here is the plot for only t -> {0,50}:

- [Plot of y(t)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%280.62%20Exp%5B-0.564%20t%5D%2b1%29%2a%28-1.62%2b0.0749%2ai%29/%28Exp%5B%280.0510%2b0.24%2ai%29%20t%5D%20%29,%20%7Bt,0,50%7D%5D%20)